"Close Enough" Matching of Rows from Two Pandas Data Frames Comparing Multiple Columns
I have two data frames, with two columns in common.  I want to flag records in the 1st data frame that have a two-column match in the 2nd, where the second match is "fuzzy".  Neither column is a unique key; values can be repeated in both of them.  Imagine, for example, my matching columns are a city-column and a date-column.
Input dataframe 1 (df1):



city
date




New York
1/1/2024


New York
1/5/2024


Chicago
1/2/2024


Chicago
1/5/2024


Houston
1/3/2024



Input dataframe 2 (df2):



city
date




New York
1/2/2024


Chicago
1/5/2024



My desired output is to flag as True every record in df1 that has a record in df2 that exactly matches the city AND matches within one day of the date, with all other records flagged as False.
Output dataframe 1:



city
date
paired




New York
1/1/2024
True


New York
1/5/2024
False


Chicago
1/2/2024
False


Chicago
1/5/2024
True


Houston
1/3/2024
False



If I was seeking exact matches on both columns, the problem would be very straightforward: I would zip the two columns to be used for matching together, and apply an isin test inside of a where method:
df1['zipcol'] = list(zip(df1.city, df1.date))
df2['zipcol'] = list(zip(df2.city, df2.date))
df1['paired'] = np.where(df1['zipcol'].isin(df2['zipcol']), True, False)
#some overhead to drop the zipped columns

What is the most efficient way to perform this type of comparison, except with one (or more) criteria that is not exact, but defined in terms of the values from the 2nd data frame being within a range of values centered on values from the 1st?
Final note:  I am not worried about the possibility of duplicate matches here. If one-to-many matches do occur, they can be handled in a post-processing step later on.

Note that you wouldn't use np.where for an exact match, but rather a merge: df1.merge(df2.assign(paired=1), on=['city', 'date'], how='left').assign(paired=lambda x: x['paired'].eq(1))

First convert to datetime:
df1['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['date'])
df2['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['date'])

Then use merge_asof:
tmp = pd.merge_asof(
    df1.reset_index().sort_values('date'), 
    df2.assign(paired=df2['date']).sort_values('date'), 
    on='date', 
    by='city', 
    tolerance=pd.Timedelta('1 day'), 
    direction="nearest"
)

tmp['paired'] = tmp['paired'].notna()

out = tmp.set_index('index').sort_index().rename_axis(None)

out
       city       date  paired
0  New York 2024-01-01    True
1  New York 2024-01-05   False
2   Chicago 2024-01-02   False
3   Chicago 2024-01-05    True
4   Houston 2024-01-03   False


Setup, for reference
import pandas as pd
data1 = {'city': ['New York', 'New York', 'Chicago', 'Chicago', 'Houston'], 'date': ['1/1/2024', '1/5/2024', '1/2/2024', '1/5/2024', '1/3/2024']}
data2 = {'city': ['New York', 'Chicago'], 'date': ['1/2/2024', '1/5/2024']}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)


about @wjandrea's comment (mistaken recommendation to assign a scalar for error prevention)
If there is a null in the date column, which is is used as a merge key, an error is thrown, and it has nothing to do with what value you use for the non-key column (paired). Try running the code below to see.
df2 with a null:
data2 = {'city': ['New York', 'Chicago'], 'date': ['1/2/2024', None]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
df2['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['date'])

Changed .assign(paired=df2['date']) to .assign(paired=1):
pd.merge_asof(
    df1.reset_index().sort_values('date'),
    df2.assign(paired=1).sort_values('date'),
    on='date',
    by='city',
    tolerance=pd.Timedelta('1 day'),
    direction="nearest"
)

ValueError: Merge keys contain null values on right side


Regarding .notna(), what if df2['date'] contains NaT? Or would there be an error on the merge in that case? You could avoid that entirely by assigning a scalar instead, e.g. .assign(paired=1), like in mozway's answer.

@wjandrea merge_asof does not allow null_value to be included in the key. it has nothing to do with creating a column with a scalar.

You need a merge_asof with direction='nearest' and 1 day of tolerance.
The important points are:

convert the dates to_datetime
maintain the index with reset_index (a merge doesn't maintain the index)
sort the dates with sort_values
add a temporary column to df2 (here with value 1) to act as flag for values present in df2.

df1['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['date'])
df2['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['date'])

df1['paired'] = (
    pd.merge_asof(
        df1.reset_index().sort_values(by='date'),
        df2.sort_values(by='date').assign(flag=1),
        on='date',
        by='city',
        direction='nearest',
        tolerance=pd.Timedelta('1d')
    )
    .set_index('index')['flag']
    .eq(1)
)

Output:
       city       date  paired
0  New York 2024-01-01    True
1  New York 2024-01-05   False
2   Chicago 2024-01-02   False
3   Chicago 2024-01-05    True
4   Houston 2024-01-03   False


@wjandrea out of curiosity, why the swap of reset_index/sort_values? For aesthetics?

Can this be extended to more than one field, or is only a single approximate match allowed?

@mozway Yeah, for aesthetics, but on second thought I undid it because it's functionally slightly different.

@NaiveBayesian you can only have one "approximate" field, but several exact ones

@wjandrea ironically, I had formatted my post with black (actually blue as I prefer single quotes) and manually moved the by on the same line, but I guess that's back to purity :p

I got pretty much the same solution :) The only real difference was I put the on column name into a variable for flexibility: on = 'date' ... .sort_values(on) ... on=on,

That's a good idea. Of note, the fact that the temporary column is called "paired" doesn't matter. It would also be called "flag". Only the df1['paired'] = defines the name.

@mozway That's a good point. You know, I actually tried re-running your code and got an error KeyError: 'paired' (not quite sure why), but changing the temp column name to flag fixed it. So I'd change it if I were you :)

@wjandrea because if you run the code twice then df1 already has the target column and it will get a suffix during the merge. I'll change it for safety ;)
